# Adding column in Status indicator

Tags: 2010, object-model, business-intelligence

I have requirement that adding one more field in the Status indicator list view programmetically.is there way to extend the Staus indicator list using programmetically?.How can i acheive this?

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty known that Status indicators ignore custom columns( I've tried with Required even) in both New/Edit/Display forms unfortunately. The bad thing is that even in Event Handlers it behaves strangely.

Personally, i didn't found an appropriate solution for doing so, except for keeping related information in another list and use Web part connection to show it as the indicator is selected.

Hope somebody else proves differently,but these are my 2-cents!